# How to make drop down parameter in crystal reports

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have certain parameters in the crystal reports which would be passed directly into Stored procedure in sql . Parameter A has 5 values and I want to enable them for users so that when user opens up the report , he is able to select any number of parameters values in the drop down based on which report data would be filtered.
Please advise

Comment: Are the parametes values static or those coming from database

Comment: Have you placed the parameter on the design?

Comment: @Siva Parameters are static , values passed into the parameters would be passed into the Stored procedure . Parameters are Placed on the Crystal Report , when opened ,user should be prompt to select multiple values from the drop down of parameter

Answer (score 1):

For a parameter to select multiple values you need to enable the option allow multiple values to true.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As I know, in designing a report in Crystal Reports you can use a simple `SELECT` like this:

```
SELECT CAST(0 AS int) AS Id, CAST(0 AS varchar(0)) As Name
```

That will give you two fields like `Id, Name` and you can use them in your report.

Now, you can use that type of `SELECT` statement instead of running a stored procedure like `EXEC SP1 @P1 = P1, @P2 = P2` just inside of your report designer and running that stored procedure when you are filling the Data-Set of your report.